# DataFrame column of lists to dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

```
lists
Out[140]: 
0          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, ...
1          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, ...
2          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, ...
3          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, ...
4          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, ...
                                 ...                        
43245                         [2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
43246                               [2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
43247                               [2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
43248                                     [2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 5]
ln_dict                 {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 6, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 5}
Name: Ln, Length: 43250, dtype: object
```

I made a mistake in my previous post, he did give me the correct answer, but apparently i need it in the form of a dictionary.

For instance, row 0 needs to look like:

```
0          {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3, 9: 6, 10: 4, 11: 4, 12: 4, 13: 5, ...
```

Comment: what previous post? can you please add more context to help us understand better

Comment: Didn't get the logic

Comment: Here is the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66158362/dataframe-with-array-of-letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your series object is called `lists`, as per the output you show above, you can try this -

```
lists.apply(lambda x: dict(enumerate(x,1)))
```

```
0    {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: ...
1    {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: ...
2    {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: ...
3    {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 6, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 5, 8: ...
4     {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 6, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 5, 7: 5, 8: 5}
5     {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 6, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 5, 7: 5, 8: 5}
6                 {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 6, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 5}
dtype: object
```

---

I got the column name from [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66158362/dataframe-with-array-of-letters).

Comment: Glad to help anytime.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]],[[2, 3, 6, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]]], columns=['a'])

df['a'] = df.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(range(1, len(x['a'])+1),x['a'])))
```

```
    a
0   {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: ...
1   {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 6, 4: 4, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 5, 8: ...
```